# How can I make AngularJS 1.2 rc store the actual values in a <select>?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following object:

```
[
  {"id":"150c67d4-952b-45b0-b287-f651a5f6d82b","name":"xx"},
  {"id":"9001f011-3a0c-4d45-a0fb-eabb4c83ff83","name":"yy"},
  {"id":"9b8b93af-cfef-451a-8dda-7373d9154f60","name":"zz"}
]
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<select
   data-ng-model="option.selectedCreatedBy"
   data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.userProfilesPlus">
   <option style="display: none" value="">Select User</option>
</select>
```

The result is:

```
<select 
   data-ng-model="option.selectedCreatedBy" 
   data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.userProfilesPlus" 
><option style="display: none" value="" class="">Select User</option>
 <option value="0" selected="selected">*</option>
 <option value="1">xx</option>
 <option value="2">yy</option>
 <option value="3">zz</option></select>
```

How can I make this so that the values stored are the actual id's ?

Comment: The value field in `option` doesn't matter as long as you access by model `option.selectedCreatedBy` you will get the real id defined in the object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are using the `ng-option` to generate the option list, you don't have control over the values generated for options. For an array it is the index into the array.

If you want to have specific value in the option field, you have to use `ng-repeat` for it.

In any case, you should not be very concern about specific of html generated, angular can update model correctly in any case.